# how to convert Index into list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

My index:

```
Index([u'Newal', u'Saraswati Khera', u'Tohana'], dtype='object')
```

I have to convert this format into list with  following format:

```
['Newal','SaraswatiKhera','Tohana']
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.tolist.html) or `list`:

```
print df.index.tolist()

print list(df.index)
```

But the fastest solution is convert `np.arry` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.values.html) [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.tolist.html)  (thanks [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179155/how-to-convert-index-into-list#comment61894194_37179182))

```
print df.index.values.tolist()
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.Index([u'Newal', u'Saraswati Khera', u'Tohana'])
print idx
Index([u'Newal', u'Saraswati Khera', u'Tohana'], dtype='object')

print idx.tolist()
[u'Newal', u'Saraswati Khera', u'Tohana']

print list(idx)
[u'Newal', u'Saraswati Khera', u'Tohana']
```

If you need encode `UTF-8`:

```
print [x.encode('UTF8') for x in idx.tolist()]
['Newal', 'Saraswati Khera', 'Tohana']
```

Another solution:

```
print [str(x) for x in idx.tolist()]
['Newal', 'Saraswati Khera', 'Tohana']
```

but it would fail if the unicode string characters do not lie in the ascii range.

**Timings**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#random dataframe
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)))
df.columns = list('ABC')
df.index = [u'Newal', u'Saraswati Khera', u'Tohana']
print df

print df.index
Index([u'Newal', u'Saraswati Khera', u'Tohana'], dtype='object')

print df.index.tolist()
[u'Newal', u'Saraswati Khera', u'Tohana']

print list(df.index)
[u'Newal', u'Saraswati Khera', u'Tohana']

print df.index.values.tolist()
[u'Newal', u'Saraswati Khera', u'Tohana']


In [90]: %timeit list(df.index)
The slowest run took 37.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.18 µs per loop

In [91]: %timeit df.index.tolist()
The slowest run took 22.33 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.75 µs per loop

In [92]: %timeit df.index.values.tolist()
The slowest run took 62.72 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 787 ns per loop
```

Comment: Good summary, note that the ways using print will be longer to run (~3.5 times longer according to %timeit)

Comment: Good idea, I add it.

Comment: If performance is key use the underlying np array `df.index.values.tolist()` this will be faster than the other methods

Comment: Thank you, EdChum, I add it to solution.

Comment: I find no appreciable different between `df.index.tolist()` and `df.index.values.tolist()`

Comment: @BallpointBen - Do you test it in large DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, 100 million elements in the index.

Comment: @BallpointBen - And no difference? If yes, maybe use newer version of pandas like used in this answer.

Comment: @BallpointBen - I just test it `idx = pd.Index([u'Newal', u'Saraswati Khera', u'Tohana'] * 10000000, dtype='object')` and then `In [17]: %timeit idx.tolist()
277 ms ± 21.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [18]: %timeit idx.values.tolist()
220 ms ± 1.81 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: Just seems there is `+-21.2ms`, so it seems same.